# scrapy giving a different output than on website, problem with geo location?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm really a newbie in all of this and am just trying to learn a bit more about this.
So I had a lot of help to get this going but now I'm stuck on a very weird problem. 
I am scraping info from a grocery store in Australia. As I'm located in the state of Victoria when I go on a website the price of a Redbull is 10.5$ but as soon as I run my script I get 11.25$.
I am guessing it might have to do with a geolocation...but not sure.
I basically need some help as to where to look to find how to get the right price I get when I go to the website.
Also, I noticed that when I do go to the same website from my phone it gives me the price of 11.25$, but if I go to the app of the store I get the accurate price of 10.5$.

```
import json
import scrapy


class SpidervenderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidervender'
    allowed_domains = ['woolworths.com.au']
    start_urls = ['https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/306165/red-bull-energy-drink']

    def parse(self, response):
        product_schema = json.loads(response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]::text').get())
        yield {
            'title': product_schema['name'],
            'price': product_schema['offers']['price']
        }
```

So the code works perfectly but the price is (I presume) for a different part of Australia.

Comment: Are you using a proxy in your browser or spider? Have you checked the source code of the browser response, see if it has the price that the spider gets anywhere?

Comment: No proxy used. I just checked the source code and found that price I am getting which is 11.25$ which is different from what is on website.
Now I need to figure out where the hell is it pulling 10.50$ from.
Have any ideas?
p.s. thanks for the help

Comment: Nothing specific, I would follow the steps at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html to find out the source, basically use your browser Network tool (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html)